# Custom date format not recognized by chart

Tags: date, charts, google-sheets, formatting

I'm setting up a simple line graph in Google Sheets based on a couple of columns of data. The first column is the date of each point of data, and I've successfully got the line chart set up with that column as my x-axis. I'd like to have the chart arranged so that when I miss a day, there's a gap that shows up in the chart. (i.e. I want it to recognize that these are dates.)

From my research, I believe Sheets does this automatically if the column is formatted as a `DATE`. I've set the column up as a Custom Date Format with the format `YEAR.MONTH.DAY` (e.g. `2019.08.21`) but the chart doesn't seem to recognize this. What am I missing?

Link to a copy of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p-D014lvhCK7S16VPd6zJEyqSW_O_t01rcb4ztEhYH4/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Copy shared. Good thought.

Comment: any visual of that "gap" you request? how exactly should it look like?

Comment: See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/583/how-to-plot-time-series-graph-in-google-sheets except that in my case I have a custom date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a regular date `mm/dd/yyyy` formatted as your desired date `yyyy.mm.dd` - then the chart will pick it like a regular date, not text string/plain text which just look like a date:

[image: 0]

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110LE-jWlL0o4Qa9SRm-YCgxu7dxn8xPmhPenbwH9_X0/copy)

Comment: It looks like with this approach, I'd have to enter the date in MM/DD/YYYY format. I'm using YYYY.MM.DD because that's easiest for me to enter.

Comment: in that case you could setup en "entry column" where you enter your date in your prefered format and convert it with arrayformula to valid date in another column which will be used by chart

Comment: @AlexanderBrooks https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110LE-jWlL0o4Qa9SRm-YCgxu7dxn8xPmhPenbwH9_X0/edit#gid=1373827604